# How to handle class [B in a custom ClassLoader

Tags: java, scala, reflection

I want to send class data through the Scala RemoteActor API. I made a custom ClassLoader but it has trouble loading the class `[B`. I have found out that it represents `byte[]` in Java. How could I handle this problem? Here is the loadClass method of my ClassLoader.

```
override def loadClass(name: String): Class[_] = {
if(ClientEntry.verbose) println("loadClass "+name)
var c = findLoadedClass(name)

if (c == null) {
  try {
    c = findSystemClass(name)
  } catch { case _ => null}
}
if (c == null) {
  try {
    c = defaultloader.loadClass(name)
  } catch {
    case _ => c = loadRemoteClass(name)
  }
}
  resolveClass(c)
  c
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to *load* a class through `RemoteActor` - equivalent to piping the .class file to the remote JVM - or are you just trying to send a `Class` object representing a class known to both systems?

Comment: I'm sending an `Array[Byte]` to define the class. I guess it's the first then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java class `byte[]` is synonymous with `Array[Byte]` so if you encounter a class named `"[B"` then one could simply get the class directly `classOf[Array[Byte]]` since is a primitive of the language.

```
if ( name == "[B" )
  c = classOf[Array[Byte]]
```

Unfortunately, things are more complicated than that. There are more java array primitives that need to be handled as well. See how the following classes are named.

```
println( classOf[Array[Boolean]].getName ) // "[Z"
println( classOf[Array[Byte]].getName ) // "[B"
println( classOf[Array[Char]].getName ) // "[C"
println( classOf[Array[Int]].getName ) // "[I"
println( classOf[Array[Long]].getName ) // "[J"
println( classOf[Array[Double]].getName ) // "[D"
println( classOf[Array[Float]].getName ) // "[F"
println( classOf[Array[String]].getName ) // "[Ljava.lang.String;"
println( classOf[Array[Any]].getName ) // "[Ljava.lang.Object;"
println( classOf[Array[Option[Any]]].getName ) // "[Lscala.Option;"
```

Notice the type erasure on the last one. And also nested arrays need to be handled as well.

```
println( classOf[Array[Array[Boolean]]].getName ) // "[[Z"
println( classOf[Array[Array[Array[Boolean]]]].getName ) // "[[[Z"
println( classOf[Array[Array[Option[_]]]].getName ) // "[[Lscala.Option;"
println( classOf[Array[Array[Array[Option[_]]]]].getName ) // "[[[Lscala.Option;"
```

Comment: That explains a lot. So if the code requests class [[B for example should I return classOf[Array[Array[Byte]]]? And how could I implement that? I have trouble using instances java.lang.Class[_] as types.

Comment: java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(inner,0).getClass() seems to work for creating an array of the class inner

Answer (score 1):

Array classes must be loaded with `Class.forName`:

```
if (name(0) == '[') Class.forName(name, true, classLoader)
else classLoader.loadClass(name)
```